# React JS how to remember the clicked item in a list when I pass to next page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, list, material-ui, listitem

I listed some countries in my Country.js page using ListItem. I created a CodeSandbox and this is the link for it:

[My Code](https://codesandbox.io/s/country-stuwd)

I want the program to remember the clicked list item in the list in Country.js file and when I go to next page (press the next button) and back again (press the back button), the selected item before going to next page should also be selected. Sorry for the bad stylings, I did not add them.

Note: I implemented this feature in forms (radio group) but, I could not do this in a list.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your state is currently at the level of your CountryList component so every time this component is unmounted, its state disappear.

What you need to do is lift up the state of the component in your UserForm component so it won't disappear when you change page

Comment: Hi @Axnyff, I searched the term lifting state up and I see that, the tutorial uses onChange and value parameters in the component. Does all components have these parameters?

Comment: It's just a convention, you can name those the way you want. In your case, something like chosenCountry and onChangeCountry should be better

Comment: Okay, I'll change my code. When I finish, I'll write again.

Comment: In your code CountryList is still using the same state. It's state know should come from parent component

Comment: I modified your example a bit and the state seems correct ( according to the console.log). Howerver, something seems weird with your ui, I can't figure out why: https://codesandbox.io/s/country-forked-k2zq5?file=/src/CountryList.js

Comment: I did not add the stylings therefore the page looks ugly. Probably, the reason for not remembering the item is that, if I click any item and if I click any other region that is not in List, it deselects that item. Therefore, when I click the next icon, it deselects the selected item and goes to next page. Maybe, I can edit the code as when I click next or back icon, it does not deselect it, anything except these back and next buttons, it deselects the selected one.

Answer (score 0):

there is a lot solution for this case (holds data in):

- a) **context**,
- b) **redux** - **redux persist** -  holds in persistence
- c) **sessionStorage**

Of course, the state can be transferred between the components (but only one way - there is no two way data binding as in angular)

As context and redux are more global concepts - I suggest you save the data at each step to sessionStorage and finally collect that data and send it to API or whatever.

```
// Save data to sessionStorage
    sessionStorage.setItem('Country', countryName);
    sessionStorage.setItem('FilmSurvey', surveyName);

// Get saved data from sessionStorage
    var dataCountry = sessionStorage.getItem('Country');
    var dataSurvey = sessionStorage.getItem('FilmSurvey');
```

---

Then, when it works,that you refactor it somehow.

And general advice - I recommend using **Hooks** - they are more consistent and newer

Comment: After this step, I am planning to use Redux instead of UserForm.js file. I have to reearch these terms since I do not have any knowledge about them.

Comment: redux can seems bit complicated - in this case you need to save the data with the action to store - and then refer to it mapDispatchtoProps

Comment: I do not understand this because all of the other components in my code have this feature. I used Radio Buttons in other components and I gave onChange and value parameters to buttons. But, in ListItem, I could not do this.